# How do you select records with a certain time range from MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to choose from MySQL, using PHP, records that were created for a certain period of time, if each record has creation time in timestamp?

Comment: Provide sample data, and expected output.

Comment: I have this tbl { ip( varchar(12) )| time( timestamp ) } and i want select records for day, week and month time range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to connection to the database, then run the query against the specific table you want to get data from,

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_field` BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo $row[0].','.$row[1]...
    }

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

You can find more information at - [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

Answer (score 11):

You do a query similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE creation_time BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Here it'll select all entries that have a creation time between January 1st, 2011 and March 1st, 2011.

Comment: @NiLL: Happy to help. :) If the answer solved your problem, remember to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT fields.... 
FROM tables
WHERE dates BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

`$valid = strtotime('-7 days'); //define your valid time`

then just use it to select

`"SELECT ******* WHERE time > $valid";`

but that's me. i don't like to work with dates directly in SQL. maybe you don't like too (:

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when we create an entry into the database we also save the time when that specific entry is created (mostly in the created_at column). If you want to get records that are in a specific range of time, then the following query will be helpful:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE created_at between now() - interval 30 minute and now() - interval 10 minute;
```